# Limiting ffmpeg console output even further

Tags: ffmpeg

UPDATE: See the EDIT section at the bottom

Is there a way to limit console output from ffmpeg either by setting options or processing the output? I've looked at the documentation and I've set the options available that limit the output but I hope there may be other methods that are possible to limit it even further. I've also looked at those posts I could find about ffmpeg verbocity such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/326629/how-can-i-make-ffmpeg-be-quieter-less-verbose) that discuss the -loglevel option, but it does not provide enough control.

Here is the least verbose output I can get without silencing the output completely using the -loglevel error option, which is not what I want.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -x265-params log-level=error -vtag hvc1 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text output.mp4 
Input #0, matroska,webm, from './input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : no_variable_data
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
  Duration: 00:48:46.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9619 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 326.409000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0:1: start 326.409000, end 1037.912000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:05:26.409
    Chapter #0:2: start 1037.912000, end 1516.640000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:17:17.912
    Chapter #0:3: start 1516.640000, end 2359.732000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:25:16.640
    Chapter #0:4: start 2359.732000, end 2887.009000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:39:19.732
    Chapter #0:5: start 2887.009000, end 2926.475000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:48:07.009
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 8107717
      BPS-eng         : 8107717
      DURATION        : 00:48:46.466000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:48:46.466000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 70165
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 70165
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 2965869890
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2965869890
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 1508999
      BPS-eng         : 1508999
      DURATION        : 00:48:46.475000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:48:46.475000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 274357
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 274357
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 552006284
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 552006284
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      title           : Forced
      BPS             : 105
      BPS-eng         : 105
      DURATION        : 00:00:18.518000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:18.518000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 6
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 6
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 245
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 245
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 61
      BPS-eng         : 61
      DURATION        : 00:47:20.754000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:47:20.754000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 584
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 584
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 21796
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 21796
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : SDH
      BPS             : 62
      BPS-eng         : 62
      DURATION        : 00:48:07.176000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:48:07.176000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 619
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 619
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 22653
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 22653
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (dts (dca) -> ac3 (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to './output.mp4':
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 326.409000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0:1: start 326.409000, end 1037.912000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:05:26.409
    Chapter #0:2: start 1037.912000, end 1516.640000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:17:17.912
    Chapter #0:3: start 1516.640000, end 2359.732000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:25:16.640
    Chapter #0:4: start 2359.732000, end 2887.009000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:39:19.732
    Chapter #0:5: start 2887.009000, end 2926.475000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:48:07.009
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 8107717
      BPS-eng         : 8107717
      DURATION        : 00:48:46.466000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:48:46.466000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 70165
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 70165
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 2965869890
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2965869890
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      encoder         : Lavc libx265
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 1508999
      BPS-eng         : 1508999
      DURATION        : 00:48:46.475000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:48:46.475000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 274357
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 274357
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 552006284
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 552006284
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      encoder         : Lavc ac3
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874) (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      title           : Forced
      BPS             : 105
      BPS-eng         : 105
      DURATION        : 00:00:18.518000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:18.518000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 6
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 6
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 245
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 245
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      encoder         : Lavc mov_text
frame= 1047 fps= 58 q=33.7 size=    2560kB time=00:00:44.37 bitrate= 472.6kbits/s speed=2.48x
```

And this is what I ideally would like to have:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -x265-params log-level=error -vtag hvc1 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text output.mp4 
Input #0, matroska,webm, from './input.mkv':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default) (forced)
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: subrip
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (dts (dca) -> ac3 (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to './output.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874) (default) (forced)
frame= 1047 fps= 58 q=33.7 size=    2560kB time=00:00:44.37 bitrate= 472.6kbits/s speed=2.48x
```

If there is no way to do this with ffmpeg, it would be great if someone could give an example on how to filter out all the unneeded text from the output.

EDIT:
Following the suggestion to use grep, I've come up with this which brings me nearly there. The only remaining issue is that grep makes the progress appear on continuous new lines and I haven't been able to filter for that.

```
ffmpeg -progress pipe:1 -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy -c:s mov_text output.mp4 2>&1 | egrep "Input.*|Duration.*|Stream.*|Output.*|frame=.*"
```

Gives this output:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from './input.mkv':
  Duration: 00:43:04.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7253 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default) (forced)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
Output #0, mp4, to '/output.mp4':
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (libx265) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 13978 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874) (default) (forced)
frame=92 92 fps=0.0 q=29.8 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.52 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=9.01x    
frame=17676 fps=174 q=31.2 size=       0kB time=00:00:08.04 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=7.94x    
frame=25555 fps=168 q=35.8 size=     256kB time=00:00:11.38 bitrate= 184.4kbits/s speed=7.48x    
frame=29191 fps=143 q=34.4 size=     512kB time=00:00:12.88 bitrate= 325.7kbits/s speed=6.34x
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make ffmpeg be quieter/less verbose?](https://superuser.com/questions/326629/how-can-i-make-ffmpeg-be-quieter-less-verbose)

Comment: Thanks but no, I've read that post earlier and the -loglevel scale is apparently much too coarse. The default is this 'info' level and the next quieter one 'warning' is silent.

Comment: Why? It seems you'd use some intermediate source and then run basic filtering on that for your "final" output. But knowing why you're trying to do this might allow us to present a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to create your own level of logging, you will need to do it
by yourself.

For example, you might use something like:

```
unbuffer ffmpeg … | unbuffer grep PATTERN
```

where PATTERN is a regex expression that defines the output lines
that you wish to pass-through.

Comment: This works somewhat but only with the first unbuffer command. If I include the second, there is no output. Also, the first and last line is not passed through (ffmpeg and frame). I have checked the pattern against a text file and it matches. This is my attempt: unbuffer ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy -c:s mov_text output.mp4 | egrep "^ffmpeg.*|Input.*|Stream.*|Output.*|frame=.*"

Comment: Are these lines perhaps issued to stderr?

Comment: It seems ffmpeg outputs all of its logging data to stderr. The first line missing was an error from me, the last line missing is the progress line where a tally of the processed frames is listed. This is blank and also, any user input to ffmpeg is ignored, it seems.

Comment: I've edited my question with additional information

Comment: I'm glad that my wild idea seems to be working. I understand that the remaining problem now is for new progress lines to over-write the old ones. You could perhaps add here another utility, such as `sed`, to add a carriage-return to these lines, or perhaps replace the end-of-line with a carriage-return (some testing required).